# vue router beforeRouteLeave fired twice

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am trying to create a global "unsaved changes confirm" functionality.

So whenever some form is edited, I set a global vuex state saying there's unsaved changed, and then I want the user to confirm before the route changes.

I have created a global mixin - and it works fine, except when theres nested router views - then the beforeRouteLeave is fired twice, and then the next() function doesn't work?

This is how it looks:

```
Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
        unsavedChanges() {
            return this.$store.getters["helpers/unsavedChanges"]
        }
    },
    beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) { 
        if (this.unsavedChanges) {
            this.$Modal.confirm({
                title: 'Unsaved changes',
                content: '<p>Are you sure you wish to leave the page?</p>',
                okText: 'Continue',
                cancelText: 'Cancel',
                onOk: () => {
                    next()
                },
                onCancel: () => {
                    next(false)
                }
            });
        }
    } 
})
```

It works fine whenever there's no sub router views, but if there are, then the router doesnt change, even if you click Continue and the next() function is called.

How do I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: add your router code as well